# Is there a way in R to find a combination of words (or sentences) within a certain range in a string

Tags: r, text-mining, stringr, tidytext

I'm trying to find all strings with a combination of words/sentences with other words separating them but with a fixed limit.

Example : I want the combination of "bought" and "watch" but with, at maximum, 2 words separating them.

- I bought a beautiful and shiny watch
  -> not ok because there is 4 words between "bought" and "watch" ("a beautiful and shiny")
- I bought a shiny watch -> ok because there is 2 words between "bought" and "watch" ("a shiny")

I haven't found anything close to what I wanted on R.

To find simple words/sentences in strings I'm using `str_extract_all` from `stringr` as here :

```
my_analysis <- str_c("\\b(", str_c(my_list_of_words_and_sentences, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
df$words_and_sentences_found <- str_extract_all(df$my_strings, my_analysis)
```

Comment: You are looking for a "skip gram" for something to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [skip-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#Skip-gram) for this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- tibble(id = 1:3,
             txt = c("I bought a beautiful and shiny watch", 
                     "I bought a shiny watch", 
                     "The watch is very shiny"))

tidy_ngrams <- df %>%
  ## use k for the skip, and n for what degree of n-gram:
  unnest_tokens(ngram, txt, token = "skip_ngrams", n_min = 2, n = 2, k = 2) 

tidy_ngrams
#> # A tibble: 33 × 2
#>       id ngram           
#>    <int> <chr>           
#>  1     1 i bought        
#>  2     1 i a             
#>  3     1 i beautiful     
#>  4     1 bought a        
#>  5     1 bought beautiful
#>  6     1 bought and      
#>  7     1 a beautiful     
#>  8     1 a and           
#>  9     1 a shiny         
#> 10     1 beautiful and   
#> # … with 23 more rows

tidy_ngrams %>%
  filter(ngram == "bought watch")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      id ngram       
#>   <int> <chr>       
#> 1     2 bought watch
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A way to think about it:

```
my_list2 <- list("I bought a beautiful and shiny watch", "I bought a shiny watch", 
    "It was not bought but watch")
as_words <- unlist(str_split(my_list2, ' '))
t1 <- which(as_words == 'bought')
t2 <- which(as_words == 'watch')
t1
[1]  2  9 16
t2
[1]  7 12 18
t2-t1
[1] 5 3 2
```